# how to resolve the hostname of a device in my LAN from its ip address on this LAN?

Tags: ios, macos, networking

I have to resolve the hostname of a device in my LAN from its ip address on this LAN.
I have some code that works for external ip address but not the internally connected devices .

Below i have attached the code .

if you have any idea to get hostname of remote machine from it's IP in iOS/OSX, it'll make my day.

```
  int error;
struct addrinfo *results = NULL;

error = getaddrinfo("173.194.34.24", NULL, NULL, &results);
if (error != 0)
{
    NSLog (@"Could not get any info for the address");

}

for (struct addrinfo *r = results; r; r = r->ai_next)
{
    char hostname[NI_MAXHOST] = {0};
    error = getnameinfo(r->ai_addr, r->ai_addrlen, hostname, sizeof hostname, NULL, 0 , 0);
    if (error != 0)
    {
        continue; // try next one
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog (@"Found hostname: %s", hostname);
        break;
    }
}


freeaddrinfo(results);
```

or with NSHost

```
NSLog(@"%@ \n%@",[NSHost currentHost],[[NSHost hostWithAddress:@"172.17.241.61"] names]);
```

Comment: Do you have a DNS server in your LAN? If not, what hostnames do you expect to get?

Comment: Yeah I have DNS server, how to  get host name via DNS server

Comment: You should set your DNS server's IP to your network configuration or configure it to your DHCP server. Then configure your DNS server to forward requests, which cannot be resolved to your ISP's DNS server.

Comment: It seems for me every time CFHostStartInfoResolution fails. How to solve it, is there any alternative ?

Comment: Are you calling CFHostStartInfoResolution with kCFHostNames?

Comment: Yes, but CFHostStartInfoResolution fails every time

Comment: Does it set the error parameter to some value? Could you please include the code where you call CFHostStartInfoResolution.

Comment: Did you get an answer to this question ?

Answer (score 1):

Only way to make a DNS lookup directly to a specific DNS is to implement the protocol yourself or use some library.

https://serverfault.com/questions/173187/what-does-a-dns-request-look-like

https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt

https://github.com/adeboer/rfc1035lib